# Why we are dividing rate of reaction with respect to a species by its stoichiometry coefficient to find rate of that particular reaction

Tags: kinetics, concentration, stoichiometry

If there is a reaction like this

$$\ce{ H2 + Cl2 -> 2HCl}$$

I can understand that each individual species (reactant or product) can have different rates and we can compare them like this,

$$-\frac{d[\ce{H2}]}{dt} =- \frac{d[\ce{Cl2}]}{dt} = \frac{d[\ce{HCl}]}{2dt}$$

But I'm having problem with defining the rate of reaction (for the chemical reaction shown above) as the above expressions.

Can someone please explain me why it is like this?

Comment: You are missing negative signs, but think about this: the rate of decrease, in either reactant concentration, is half the rate at which product concentration increases. Simply, when one hydrogen molecule bites the dust, two HCl molecules are produced.

Comment: Yeah but why rate of reaction of this reaction is [HCl] /2dt why it can't be - 2[Cl2]/dt.why we have to go for simplest ratio(dividing by stoicheometry) .???

Comment: Well, so long as you are consistent and others know what you are doing, no problem. The 2 has to go somewhere.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is simple: The reaction rate must be the same regardless of the component rate you use to describe it. The reaction does not go faster nor slower if we describe it by the rate of HCl or Cl2.

Comment: If rate of reaction with respect to HCl is 4 and with respect to cl2 is 2.  Then if we divide them by stoicheometry we will be getting 2 as the rate of reaction for the above reaction. Why can't i multiply the rate of reaction with respect to cl2 by 2 where it will be2*2=4 and say rate of reaction of the sytem is 4, Instead of dividing HCl formation rate by 2.

Comment: What if there were several different st. coefs? What number would you choose for such multiplication?

Comment: Will dividing everything by stoicheometry give the true rate for that particular reaction? Can we find the real rate of a paticuler reaction by dividing it by stoicheometry.

Comment: So is that mean we are dividing by stoicheometry to have a constant value for rate. Its not actually the real rate of that reaction??

Comment: Reaction rate is convention, there is no true reaction rate. Important thing is to keep this convention clear, not deliberate. If there was 2A + 3B -> C + 4D,  which (absolute value ) of component rates would you choose as reaction rate?

Comment: This is what my problem is. I don't know, there are 4 components where all 4 has different reaction rate. But according to what  i have learnt, i have to choose C component as it have stoicheometry 1.

Comment: I think i got it. Its a rule we have to divide the reaction rate with related to a component by its stoicheometry. Thank you soo muchhh